# What is the difference of getting Type by using GetType() and typeof()?

Tags: c#, .net, typeof, gettype

Which one is the preferred way to get the type?

Comment: **Moderator note**: I reopened and closed to remove the legacy duplicate notice. Do not take this as my endorsement of the accuracy of the duplicate

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can only use `typeof()` when you know that type at compile time, and you're trying to obtain the corresponding `Type` object. (Although the type could be a generic type parameter, e.g. `typeof(T)` within a class with a type parameter `T`.) There don't need to be any instances of that type available to use `typeof`. The operand for `typeof` is always the *name* of a type or type parameter. It can't be a variable or anything like that.

Now compare that with `object.GetType()`. That will get the actual type of the object it's called on. This means:

- You don't need to know the type at compile time (and usually you don't)
- You *do* need there to be an instance of the type (as otherwise you have nothing to call `GetType` on)
- The actual type doesn't need to be accessible to your code - for example, it could be an internal type in a different assembly

One odd point: `GetType` will give unexpected answers on nullable value types due to the way that boxing works. A call to `GetType` will always involve boxing *any* value type, including a nullable value type, and the boxed value of a nullable value type is either a null reference or a reference to an instance of a non-nullable value type.

Comment: `One odd point` - can you show?

Comment: @Aarnihauta: Well I've explained what will happen... I don't want to add a complete example there, as it would dwarf the rest of the answer.

Answer (score 9):

GetType() works at runtime, typeof() is a compile-time operator.

So,

```
// untested, schematic
void ShowType(Object x)
{
   Write(x.GetType().Name);  // depends on actual type
   // typeof(x) won't actually compile
   Write(typeof(x).Name);   // always System.Object
}

ShowType("test");
```

Will print System.String and System.Object.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4217514/60761) for  a better example.

Comment: Actually, `typeof` can't be used with an instance, so `typeof(x)` won't compile.

Comment: @Romain: You're right, added a comment. You can demonstrate it somewhat  like this using a Generic method.

Comment: typeof(instance) won't compile would it ?

Answer (score 2):

GetType is a virtual method on Object - this means given an instance of a class, you can retrieve the corresponding Type object.

typeof is a C# operator - this is used to perform a compile time lookup i.e. Given a Symbol representing a Class name, retrieve the Type object for it.

```
if (typeof(String) == "test".GetType())
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the same, and the problem appears when you use
inheritance.

I.e.:

`WebPage1` inherits from `Page`, and this one inherits also from `Object`, so if you test for `(new WebPage1()).GetType() == typeof(object)` it'll return false because the types are diferent, but when you test using the `is` operator it's true.

`((new WebPage1()) is object)` is true because `(new WebPage1())` is an object of type `WebPage1`, and also a `Page` and an `object`.

The types might be different, but `is` checks if you can cast safely to
this type.