# How to store a List of classes in C#?

Tags: c#, list, class, generics, reflection

In Java I am able to have a list of classes like:

```
List<Class>
```

But how do I do this in C#?

Comment: Do you actually mean a list of types, or a generic list?

Comment: `var list = new List<ClassName>();` ??

Comment: A list of Objects of calss `Class` or a list of actual Classes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question is asking for a .Net equivalent of `java.lang.Class<T>`

Comment: yes that right so I can store a variety of classes

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Storing the class types

If you mean a list of *actual classes*, not *instances of a class*, then you can use `Type` instead of `Class`. Something like this if you have instances of each class:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(someClassInstance.GetType());
types.Add(someOtherClassInstance.GetType());
```

Or this if you know the actual classes:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(typeof(SomeClass));
types.Add(typeof(SomeOtherClass));
```

More on `typeof(...)` vs `...GetType()` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4537981/1175496)

### Instantiating the types

To actually instantiate a class given a classes `Type` you can use `Activator` or reflection. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/981344/1156119) for information on that. It can get a little complicated however when the compiler doesn't know about the constructors/parameters and such.

```
// Create an instance of types[0] using the default constructor
object newObject = Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]);
```

Or alternatively

```
// Get all public constructors for types[0]
var ctors = types[0].GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public);

// Create a class of types[0] using the first constructor
var object = ctors[0].Invoke(new object[] { });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but how would I then instantiate an instance of one of the types added to the list?

Comment: @user1592512 That's not the question you asked.

Comment: @user1592512 updated with some info on instantiation.

Comment: I don't see that you can use GetType() on a non-instantiated class

Comment: @Allstar It looks like typeof(ClassName) will work.

Answer (score 1):

The same basic syntax works in C#:

```
List<YourClass> list = new List<YourClass>();
```

This requires you to have `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file, which is the [namespace which provides most of the generic collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx).

If you are attempting to store a list of types, you can use `List<System.Type>`.  Instances of those types could then be constructed via [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) (which accepts the type) as needed.

Comment: Java 5 was released in September 2004. .NET 2.0 was released in November 2005.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fixed - was being dumb ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Create the list
    List<ClassName> classList = new List<ClassName>();

    // Create instance of your object
    ClassName cn = new ClassName();

    // Add the object to the list
    classList.Add(cn);
```