# Insert instead of update for history data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, change-tracking, entity-framework-6.1

I am using EF 6.1 Code First and want to track history data by using a model which (simplified) looks like this:

```
public class Customer : IHistoryData<CustomerData>
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<CustomerData> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerData : HistoricalData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public interface IHistoryData<T> where T : HistoricalData
{
    ISet<T> Versions { get; set; }
}

public class HistoricalData
{
    public int VersionID { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidUntil { get; set; }
}
```

They are wired up in the DbContext in the following manner:

```
modelBuilder.Ignore<HistoricalData>();
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customers").HasMany(c => c.Versions).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(cd => cd.ParentID);
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerData>().Map(m => m.ToTable("CustomerData")).HasKey(cd => new { cd.VersionID, cd.ParentID });
```

Now to track different Customer versions, I need to perform an insert instead of an update for changes to CustomerData. For this I hook into `SaveChangesAsync()` of `DbContext`:

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<HistoricalData>().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified))
    {
        InsertInsteadOfUpdate(entry);
    }
    return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Now I am not sure how to implement `InsertInsteadOfUpdate()`, this is my approach so far:

```
private void InsertInsteadOfUpdate<T>(DbEntityEntry<T> oldEntry) where T : HistoricalData
{
    // Get a copy of the modified data 
    var newEntry = ???
    // Modified entry has ended
    var originalValues = oldEntry.OriginalValues;
    originalValues["ValidUntil"] = DateTime.Now;
    oldEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(originalValues);
    // New entry has started
    newEntry.ValidFrom = DateTime.Now;
    Set<T>().Add(newEntry);
}
```

However, I have no idea how to get a new copy/clone of the `DbEntityEntry<CustomerData>`. And because I both need to modify the "old" entry (to set `ValidUntil`) and insert a new entry, I need two different entries.

How would I go about that? Or am I on the wrong track completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DbSet<T> dbSet = Context.Set<T>();
T newEntry = dbSet.Create();
dbSet.Attach(newEntry);
newEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(oldEntry);
```

Comment: I considered this, but as I remember it did not work because `HistoricalData` is an abstract base class not mapped to a table and so calling `Set<HistoricalData>` did not work. (`T` ends up being `HistoricalData` because of the way I query the ChangeTracker)

Comment: What happens if you add a `DbSet<HistoricalData>` property to the context?

Comment: I have no idea. But I can't imagine how EF would be able to `Create()` an entity from a Set of abstract base classes, so I don't see that approach working. I would somehow have to get a Set of the subclass instead. (i.e. somehow get `T` to be the subclass instead of `HistoryData`)

Comment: I think you should try the code I have posted. You are passing a concrete class to your generic method so the correct DbSet will be used - I have a similar method that does work. As an aside - `HistoricalData` isn't marked abstract in your question.

Comment: You are right about it not being abstract in the question, sorry. I changed it to abstract in the meantime, because it makes no sense to instantiate the base class.

Comment: You say you need to "somehow get T to be the subclass instead of HistoryData" but it must be a subclass if HistoryData is abstract

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you are wrong. To make sure, I ran a separate test myself. Try [this code](http://pastebin.com/5rTFGp8K) and you will find that it will assign the abstract base class to T instead of the subclass. That's the reason I cannot use `Context.Set<T>();` when I pass objects retrieved via `ChangeTracker.Entries<HistoricalData>()`.

Comment: What does your test show you if you use GetType instead of typeof ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4537981/150342

Comment: Probably the actual subtype, but I cannot use GetType to Call `Set<T>`. The only way to do this with GetType that I can see is by using reflection, which will likely screw up my performance if used at such a critical point, so this is not really my favorite option.

Comment: So if `GetType` returns the actual subtype do you think that perhaps you have actually managed to "somehow get T to be the subclass instead of HistoryData"