# typeof(T) vs new T().GetType()

Tags: c#

Are the two expressions guaranteed to be identical?

In a generic method `Foo<T> where T : new()` ... is this expression *always* `true`?

`typeof(T) == new T().GetType()`

I don't see how it could be false, but perhaps I'm missing an edge-case.

I don't think this is addressed in any of the following related questions:

- [Type Checking: typeof, GetType, or is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is)
- [When and where to use GetType() or typeof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312111/when-and-where-to-use-gettype-or-typeof)
- [What is the difference of getting Type by using GetType() and typeof()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537945/what-is-the-difference-of-getting-type-by-using-gettype-and-typeof)

Comment: This code generates objects of the concrete System.RuntimeType object.  [Quote:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-7.0) *all classes beginning with the word Runtime are created only once per object in the system and support comparison operations*

Comment: A little tangential, but `typeof(T)` doesn't care about the constructor parameters of `T` are. `new T().GetType()` does: it requires a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`typeof(T)` and `new T().GetType()` are not quite identical. In fact, `new T().GetType()` is not "safe".

Consider when `T` is an `int?` or something similar, then `new T()` will result in `null` - actually an instance of `int?` with `HasValue = false`, which is actually a struct. Boxing a nullable value type that has no value results in `null`, and calling a method on it that is inherited from `object` will box the value first. So `new T().GetType()` throws a null reference exception in this case.

> is this expression always true
> `typeof(T) == new T().GetType()`

It might be that it is never false (ie either true or does not evaluate to a value), but I may be overlooking some other strange edge case.

Comment: I think that a constructor for `T` is welcome to throw an exception too, but I don't think that `typeof(T)` can throw.

Comment: @Wyck I certainly agree that it's _permitted_ ... but I might dispute "welcome" :P :D

Answer (score 2):

> In a generic method `Foo<T> where T : new()` ... is this expression always true?
>
> `typeof(T) == new T().GetType()`

Sadly, no. For reference types (including nullable reference types) with default constructors then yes, but this doesn't hold true for nullable value types.

Where `T` is `int?` or `DateTime?` or any other nullable value type, the result of `new T()` is null. Calling `GetType()` on null is of course going to result in a `NullReferenceException`. But let's try something else:

```cs
static Type? WhichType<T>(T value) => value?.GetType();
```

This won't throw an exception, but may return `null`. Now let's try it out:

```cs
var type1 = WhichType<int?>(0);
var type2 = WhichType((int?)0);
```

Since nullable value types are treated specially by the C# compiler, it's not entirely clear that the result of calling `GetType()` on a nullable value type will return the inner type, and it makes some sense. Sadly it doesn't help you much when someone calls your generic method with the wrong type.

And in case you're wondering, it works on any value type not just value primitives:

```cs
public struct TestType { }

var type1 = WhichType<DateTime?>(DateTime.Now);
var type2 = WhichType<TestType?>(new TestType());
```

Where this may be an issue is when you're trying to compare the type of a value with an expected type where `T` is a nullable value type. In this case you need to use a bit of code to figure things out.

```cs
var targetType = typeof(T);
if (targetType.IsConstructedGenericType &&
    targetType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)
)
    targetType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(targetType);
```

This will unwrap the `Nullable<>` from the outer type if necessary, allowing you to compare it to the an object instance type.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean. If you are instantiating T (your `var x = new T();`) and then immediately after writing

```
Type t1 =  x.GetType();
```

and

```
if (t1 == typeof(T)) {... } // probably always true by definition
```

but what if your `T` is say a non abstract class and has subclass `R`? Well that changes the picture, doesn't it? I mean `GetType()` is a run time type (not a static compile type like `typeof(T)`). So (pseudo-code here below)

```
var x = new T();
var t1 = x.GetType(); // T 
...
x = new R();
...
bool chk1 = t1 == typeof(T); // true;
t1 = x.GetType(); // R
bool chk2 = t1 == typeof(T); // false
```

Comment: I'm unclear why you have hypothesized a materially different set of code when I gave the specific (valid) expression that I was asking about?

Comment: @Brondahl is it a materially different set of code? when you say "is this expression always true" what does the *always* imply? here above it is not true. run time typing and compile type typing are not *always* the same.

Comment: Yes, @LongChalk, `typeof(T) == new T().GetType()` and `typeof(T) == new R().GetType()` are materially different. As are "1 line expression" vs "a code block of 6+ lines, involving assignment to variables of values that never existed in the 1-line expression."

Answer (score -1):

I suppose they're always provide the same result. The difference is in that for `typeof` you don't have to create new instance of a `T` which is rather something good.
Also it's semantically more obvious if you go with `typeof` to check type rather than creating instance of an object.